# How to formate array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to store data in an array from a database.

After printing the array, I need something like this :

```
Array ( [ABBA] => ?search=ABBA [ACDC] => ?search=ACDC [Ace of Spades] => ?search=AceOfSpades)
```

But currently, I have this :

```
Array ( [url] => ?search=ABBA [title] => ABBA ) Array ( [idtitle] => ?search=ACDC [title] => ACDC  ) Array ( [idtitle] => ?search=AceOfSpades [title] => Ace of Spades )
```

Here is my code to get the data and store into the array :

```
$key = $_POST['latestQuery'];

$requete = $bdd->prepare('SELECT url, title FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :key LIMIT 10');
$requete->execute(array('key' => '%'.$key.'%'));

$result_array[] = array();

foreach($requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $search)
{
  print_r($result_array[$search['title']] = $search);
}
```

And here this my table structure :

```
url | title

$search=ACDC | ACDC
```

Do you think there is a way to formate my array?

Comment: if possible add the table structure

Comment: `$result_array[$search['title']] = $search['url']`?

Comment: @VigneswaranS It's done Sir.

Comment: @u_mulder It returns : `$search=ACDC$search=ABBA`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `print_r` from a `foreach`:

```
$result_array = array();
foreach($requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $search)
{
    $result_array[$search['title']] = $search['url'];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: It's way better but it returns :

`Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [ABBA] => $search=ABBA [ACDC] => $search=ACDC ) `

Is there a way to remove the `[0] => Array ( )` just before [ABBA]?

Comment: Check, maybe you have empty row in a table?

Comment: Or, I just see in your code - `$result_array[] = array();`. This should be - `$result_array = array();` without `[]`

Comment: Exactly. That was the problem. The problem is solved. Thank you very much for your fast help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// testing array
$yourArray = array(
    array(
        'url'=>'?search=ABBA',
        'title'=>'ABBA',
        ),
    array(
        'url'=>'?search=BABA',
        'title'=>'BABA',
        ),
    array(
        'url'=>'?search=CBAA',
        'title'=>'CBAA',
        ),
    );

// solution
$myArr = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    $myArr[$value['title']] = $value['url'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArr);
```

**Result is:**

```
Array
(
    [ABBA] => ?search=ABBA
    [BABA] => ?search=BABA
    [CBAA] => ?search=CBAA
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is a problem : how to go from that : 

`Array ( [url] => ?search=ABBA [title] => ABBA ) Array ( [idtitle] => ?search=ACDC [title] => ACDC  ) Array ( [idtitle] => ?search=AceOfSpades [title] => Ace of Spades ) `

to this : 

`$yourArray = array(
    array(
        'url'=>'?search=ABBA',
        'title'=>'ABBA',
        ),
...` ?